# d3.js in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, d3.js

Has anybody implemented an instance d3.js in drupal 7 successfully?

I plugged in the main d3.js libraries into the page header without problem... but I get all sorts of errors when I try to put code that actually draws something into a page or block...

Somebody managed it with protovis a couple of years ago... http://drupal.org/node/516282#comment-2232740 and i was trying to work along the same lines.

A module package something like the one for http://drupal.org/project/thejit would be a big timesaver.

Thanks for any clues/guidance/examples!

Comment: What errors specifically? D3 is no different from a normal javascript library and it should work by adding it to your head.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [conversation](http://drupal.org/node/1505388) in progress at Drupal.org about this.
And there's a [sandbox module](http://drupal.org/sandbox/asherry/1477334) in progress that can be grabbed at

```
git clone http://git.drupal.org/sandbox/asherry/1477334.git d3
```

D3 is amazing! 
A stable D7 module is probably 4+ months away but you never know.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some contributed module suggestions for D7, which may help to use the [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) library in a Drupal site:

- [Charts and Graphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts_graphs) (Official release available).

  > Charts and Graphs is an API for developers. It can be extended by third-party modules that want to add their own charting implementations. It does nothing by itself. It should only be installed if some other module requires it.
- [D3](https://www.drupal.org/project/d3) (Alfa release only)

  > creates visualizations as [libraries](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) (alpha version only) which allows one to add/remove visualizations, share them between modules, and integrate them with (for example: [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)) through library .info files.

  The [Basic module configuration](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/14DYgWTBUE8F9Pko3AFJd3bLNO5wXBix_lkWERheMLAw/edit#slide=id.p) presentation provide a short intro about how to use the module in combination with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).
- [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) ([sandbox](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/metzlerd/frx) only)

  Refer to [issue # 2383509](https://www.drupal.org/node/2383509) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing what errors you get would definitely help us help you.

One hint : you have to be careful about the way you add your script to prevent namespace problems. Another important thing is the scope your library is using (JQuery, $, etc.) as Drupal includes its stuff in a specific way.

Answer (score 0):

The conversation posted by @ted.strauss is now closed: it is possible to have D3.js directed layout as an engine for [graph_api](http://drupal.org/project/graphapi).

The main page for the project d3 for drupal, by asherry is https://drupal.org/project/d3.

As far as I'm concerned chart integration (which doesn't need graph_api but is directly managed by d3 module) works very well.